# How to upgrade Ubuntu version from guest user?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, upgrade, kali-linux-tools

I have recently broken my Ubuntu 18.04 by installing Kali Linux tools into it (now the internet is not working)
This was a dual boot along with Windows.
Now when I restart it I still can access (through UNetbootin option) to another kind of Ubuntu user that is spelled like this: ubuntu@ubuntu
And here I can access the internet.
So my idea is maybe try to upgrade from There to Ubuntu 20.04 and maybe it will fix everything on the go.
Is this plausible, or how can I improve my idea to fix my main broken Ubuntu ?
Right now I've started the process, but it is automatically telling me at some point that there is no more space memory left.
What should I do?

Comment: If you only have the Guest User, you can't upgrade the version there.  You're better off booting into the Live installer, copying your data you want to keep OFF your drive, then fresh-installing.  Installing the kali linux toolkit into Ubuntu is **known** to break your system so you really shouldn't be messing with that.  Just run Kali in a VM if you want the tools.

Comment: that's the huge mistake i did. now the internet is not working and many solutions i am presented require internet to run some commands. so do you have any idea on how i should proceed to fix my ubuntu? @ThomasWard

Comment: Do what @Thomas Ward said.  Trying to fix a broken system by upgrading, just leads to more worst problems.  Do a backup and clean install 18.04 or 20.04.

Comment: Ok but how to do that ?

Comment: @ttbsttsoo if you have no system then you'll have to order an installer disk or USB from someone or have a friend burn an Ubuntu instlaler ISO to a USB stick for you from their systems.  Unfortunately, if you have *no* access to the Internet at all, you're a little bit stuck

Comment: @ttbsttsoo if your Windows is working, can make the installer USB from Windows.  If you have a USB stick around with 18.04 or older version, can use that also to get a working system.

Comment: my windows is working fine. actually i installed my ubuntu from there by downloading the iso image and the unetbootin installer. i've tried to re-do the same installation process again and it asks me to restart but when i do so it is the exsiting linux system that boots in. maybe the ideal would be to delete it definietly before installing anything else. i don't know. and where to start ?

Comment: If data left on old system is backup and/or not wanted anymore, format or delete.  Make sure to double and triple check you are doing the right partition, too easy to format a wrong(Windows,important data) partition.  Would run gparted from live Ubuntu and format old Ubuntu partition to ext4 or your choice then install.  Check everything before doing a mistake.